# How to resize the layoutRoot according the content of the page in Silverlight?

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

While trying something on silverlight, i  faced with the layout problem which is that it can't be  expanded depending on the content of the  page like normal web page.

Whatever i try, i cant  tackle this problem.
( I have tried to  open ScrollBars, assigning static height and width and etc).
My .xaml file is here:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="XXXSL.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="300">
    <Border Style="{StaticResource ContentBorderStyle}">
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootGridStyle}" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border x:Name="BrandingBorder" Style="{StaticResource NavBrandingBorderStyle}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="BrandingStackPanel" Style="{StaticResource BrandingStackPanelStyle}" >
                    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource LogoIcon}" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationNameTextBlock" Style="{StaticResource ApplicationNameStyle}" Text="Metropoll Emlak Sistemi" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <Border x:Name="LinksBorder" Style="{StaticResource NavLinksBorderStyle}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="LinksStackPanel" Style="{StaticResource LinksStackPanelStyle}">
                    <HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" NavigateUri="Home" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="..." />
                    <HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" NavigateUri="XXX" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="...." />
                    <HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" NavigateUri="YYY" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="..." />
                    <HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" NavigateUri="About" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="..." />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" Style="{StaticResource NavContentBorderStyle}" Margin="45,-4,0,-38" Grid.Row="2">
                <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource LinksStackPanelStyle}">
                <navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Style="{StaticResource NavContentFrameStyle}" Navigated="ContentFrame_Navigated" NavigationFailed="ContentFrame_NavigationFailed" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" UseLayoutRounding="False" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

any help or suggestion will be  appreciated?

Comment: Make sure you remove blank lines from Xaml when pasting to StackOverflow. Then the code block will display correctly. I have fixed the above for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to resize the Silverlight hosting object to match the top level content element. Silverlight just calls out to a Javascript method to resize the container based on size changes to the root element.

This way the Browser scrollbars kick in instead of requiring Silverlight scrollbars. This also means the Silverlight page is always "full-size" as far as it is concerned.

Bearing in mind this code is from my Silverlight 2 days (very old), the concept has not changed.

In the hosting aspx page I have this Javascript function:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ResizeObject(height) {
        var host = document.getElementById("Xaml1");
        host.style.height = height + "px";
    }    
</script>
```

The `Xaml1` id was the old-school `asp:Silverlight` object, so you may need to change the targetting.

In the constructor of the root page I added a resize handler:

```
LayoutRoot.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(LayoutRoot_SizeChanged);
```

Which called the following event handler and helper method (only the height was of interest in my app at that time):

```
void LayoutRoot_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ResizeSilverlightObject(e.NewSize.Height);
}

private void ResizeSilverlightObject(double height)
{
    // Now resize the actual Silverlight container to match the layout size
    HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("ResizeObject", new object[] { height });
}
```

Comment: Hi HiTech, I did  what you say, but it gives me error named "accessing DOM element is disabled" evenif i set the value of enablehtmlaccess True in Silverlight object.

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz: If I get time I will try it in a Silverlight 4 application and post an updated version tonight.

Answer (score 0):

as HiTech Magic pointed out, the problem requires some work in the page hosting your Silverlight application.

Look for this tag in the html of the hosting page.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
```

If it doesn't contain that `width="100%" height="100%"`, that may be all that needs to be added for a fix.